# How does an Office365 user apply a retention tag rule to their mailbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, archiving, office365

I have no experience with Exchange, so please interpret my question as reflecting this.

I've just migrated two email accounts to Office365, and purchased the *Archiving for Exchange Online* add-on.  This has been assigned to the users, and I notice that automatically things have started to be archived.  After an initial panic, I now realise this is because of the default archive retention policy that exists in the Exchange Admin Portal:

[image: Default retention policy]

Inspecting the policy's retention tags, I see that one rule is applied by default to all mailboxes (`Default 2 year move to archive`), and this is why we've seen the archiving process start automatically.

However, there are many more tags (some labelled as *Personal*), that seem to allow a user to apply them individually.

[image: Retention policy tag settings]

Is this correct, and moreso, how does the user actually achieve the applicable of such a tag?

I see no options in Outlook to manage this at user level (not a bad thing!), but want to better understand the implication of me customizing settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're three tags: **Default Policy Tag** (DPT, apply for entire mailbox), **Rention Policy Tags** (RPT, apply for default folder), **Personal Tags**.

DPT and RPT are managed by Admin, the end user only has ability to custom the Personal Tags.

More information about **retention policy and tags in Exchange Online**:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297955(v=exchg.150).aspx

Besides, we can create a **[custom policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj150573(v=exchg.150).aspx)** (with some particular tags) to achieve your goal.

Comment: How does a (non-admin) user apply this to their own mailbox/folder?  I assume from these pages that they have to log into the Exchange portal?  I assumed it would be done somehow in webmail/Outlook...

Comment: Yes, only admin account can assign policy to end user. However, the Default MRM Policy will be apply for each new user mailbox by default.

Comment: Thus, they can set there personal tag by right-click a **message**, click **Assign Policy**, then select a tag.
If they want to set policy for their **personal folder**, right-click folder to open **Properties**, switch to **Policy** to configure a tag.

Comment: That answers my question - thank you.  Its weird why for messages its a context menu item, but for folders its a search through a dialog...